# No se envía correo

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, java-8, java-ee

Tengo este codigo pero no me envía el mail  me podrian apoyar es una clase
colocando mensajes se queda en el mensaje `this.addMessage("1");`  no se por que no envia de el todo el correo me podrian apoyar en el codigo si esta mal o le falta algo.

```
String correoEnvia = "correo";
tring claveCorreo = "paas"
Properties properties = new    Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.user",    correoEnvia);
properties.put("mail.password", claveCorreo);
//    Obtener la sesion   Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,    null);
try {
    introducir el código aquí
    // Crear el cuerpo del mensaje
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    Agregar    quien envía el correo
    mimeMessage.setFrom(new    InternetAddress(correoEnvia, "Aprobacion de Alata de Proveedor no    Autorizado"));

    // Los destinatarios    Entity entidad_actual = getCurrentEntity();
    Attribute att_correo = entidad_actual.getAttribute("APINST_VALOR24");
    String string_correo= att_correo.getValue().toString();

    InternetAddress[] internetAddresses = {new InternetAddress(string_correo) };

    // Agregar los destinatarios al mensaje    mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,    internetAddresses);
        
    /*************************************************************/
            
    Attribute mensaje = entidad_actual.getAttribute("APINST_EMAIL04");

    String mensajes = mensaje.getValue().toString();

    //  this.addMessage(aid);     
    // Agregar el asunto al correo    mimeMessage.setSubject("Sistema Apia ");
    // Creo la parte del    mensaje    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    mimeBodyPart.setText(" Apia: "+mensajes);

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
    mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

    this.addMessage("1");
    // Enviar el mensaje    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(correoEnvia, claveCorreo);
    this.addMessage("1b");
    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage,    mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    this.addMessage("Correo enviado1");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ya entraste a la configuración del correo de gmail y habilitaste el protocolo pop3???

Answer (score 0):

desde hace ya un tiempo google no permite la conexion con el correo de esta manera, para ello debes ir a tu correo, la parte de seguridad, autenticacion de 2 factores y generar una llave para una aplicacion de tercero. Esto te va a generar un codigo que luego lo utilizaras para enviar los correos. Ese codigo que seria la llave realmente es el password que luego utilizaras para autenticarte...

[Gestion de gmail a traves de la documentacion de google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es-419)

```
SimpleMailMessage correo = new SimpleMailMessage();
        correo.setFrom(EL CORREO QUE ESTAS USANDO);
        correo.setTo(CORREO DESTINO Y SI SON VARIOS LOS SEPARAS CON ";");
        correo.setSubject(titulo);
        correo.setText(contenido);


        javaMailSender.send(correo);
```

Aca la configuracion minima para gmail

```
host=smtp.gmail.com
port=465
username=elcorreoqueusas@gmail.com
password=llave que te da gmail
smtp.auth=true
smtp.starttls.enable=true
smtp.starttls.required=true
smtp.ssl.enable=true
```